# How to write unit test case to Reset the radio button values using angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test case to clear the checked values of radio button

By clicking the delete icon link it should clear the values

### HTML file

```
 <mat-icon  class="remove-icon" (click)="resetradioValues('gender')">delete</mat-icon>
```

### ts file

```
 resetradioValues(name: string){
    this.form.get(name).patchValue(null);
  }
```

I have written a unit test case for the above code but it is not working for me

```
it('should clear radio button values', () => {
    const param = Object.assign({},radio, { name: 'test' });
    console.log(param);
    component.resetradioValues(param.name);

    });
```

Please let me know anybody can solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will be doing an integration test by actually clicking the icon and seeing what happens.

Try:

```
it('should clear radio button values', () => {
      // arrangement
      const matIconElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-icon.remove-icon')).nativeElement;
      // click
      matIconElement.click();
      // assertions, you can assert how you like
      expect(component.form.get('test').value).toBe(null);
    });
// ========== Edit (Unit test) ==============
it('should clear radio button values', () => {
      // arrangement
      component.resetradioValues('test);
      // assertions, you can assert how you like
      expect(component.form.get('test').value).toBe(null);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use resetradioValues function in the unit test case.

Comment: I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

Comment: Somewhere in your component, I bet there is a `forEach` and that variable is null. Make sure you instantiate it in your unit test.